# How to most efficiently replace this code to vb.net version?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function fileToColHarvest(ByRef stream As Scripting.TextStream, Optional ByRef limit As Integer = 2000000, Optional ByRef unique As Boolean = False, Optional ByRef FirstSectionAsKey As Boolean = False, Optional ByRef prob As Double = 1) As Generic.List(Of String)
    Dim buffer As String
    Dim i As Integer

    If prob < 1 Then
    End If
    fileToColHarvest = New Generic.List(Of String)
    Do While (Not (stream.AtEndOfStream))
        i = i + 1
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

        'If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Rnd < 0.01 Then
        '    appendToTextFile CStr(fileToColHarvest.Count) + "|" + microsoft.visualbasic.str(i) + "|" + buffer, RESULT, ForWriting
        'End If
        buffer = stream.ReadLine
        'buffer = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Replace(buffer, " ", "+")
        If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Rnd() < prob Then
            If unique Then
                If Not FirstSectionAsKey Then
                    fileToColHarvest.AddIfNotExist(buffer)
                Else
                    fileToColHarvest.AddIfNotExist(buffer)
                End If
            Else
                fileToColHarvest.Add(buffer)
            End If
        End If
        If fileToColHarvest.Count() >= limit Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

Basically I want to get rid Scripting.TextStream.

Also I want to read the text line by line

Comment: Use `StreamReader` and `ReadLineAsync` method for reading and handling lines of file. From MSDN: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: 1) Write it in assembly. 2) Write it _really, really_ fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StreamReader` and asynchronous `ReadLineAsync` method.
Asynchronous approach will replace "ugly" `Application.DoEvents()`

```
Public Async Function FileToColHarvest(
    pathToFile As String, 
    limit As Integer, 
    isUnique As Boolean, 
    isFirstSectionAsKey As Boolean, 
    prob As Single) As Task(Of List(Of String))

    Dim lines = New List(Of String)()
    Dim uniqueLines = New HashSet(Of String)()

    Using stream As New FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open)
        Using reader As New StreamReader(stream)
            While reader.EndOfStream = False
                'Await will prevent blocking UI thread
                var line = Await reader.ReadLineAsync()

                If prob < VBMath.Rnd() Then Continue While

                ' I have removed check of isFirstSectionAsKey 
                ' because based on your code it does same thing
                If isUnique Then
                    uniqueLines.Add(line)
                    If uniqueLines.Count >= limit Then Return uniqueLines.ToList()
                Else
                    lines.Add(line)
                    If lines.Count >= limit Then Return lines
                End If
            End While            
        End Using
    End Using

    Return If(isUnique, uniqueLines.ToList(), lines)
End Function
```

Not related but `isUnique` argument divide this method in two different logic - so I suggest instead of parameter introduce two different methods

```
FileToColHarvest(...)
FileToColHarvestWithUniqueOnly(...)
```